# Redirect stdout and stderr when ampersand(&) is used between commands in bash

Tags: linux, git, bash

I am writing a bash script to pull master branch from origin.Git is initialized in every app module.

My directory structure:

```
.-----bash_script
|----app1(git init)
                  |...various modules
                  |...error.txt
                  |...output.txt
|----app2(git init)
                  |...various modules
                  |...error.txt
                  |...output.txt
```

In bash_script: $directory contains (app1 or app2... it is called in a loop)

```
cd "${directory}" && git  checkout  master  && git pull origin master >> output.txt 2>>error.txt
cd ..
```

The above two lines are called for every app.
This is what i have done so far

Problem:

1. I am only getting the `stdout/stderr` only for my last command i.e **pulling from origin** and **not from checkout**. Is it possible to get the output of whole command without writing the file names before every `&&` ?? then how
2. error.txt/output.txt files are generated inside the app directory. How can I generate them in the bash_script directory i.e one level up.
3. when git pull origin master is executed

   `From http://gitProjectUrl
   branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD`

   The above line is redirected in error.txt .

   `Already up-to-date.`

   And this line is redirected in output.txt

   **Why both the lines are not in output.txt**??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group them together using `{...}`:

```
{ cd "${directory}" && git checkout master && git pull origin master; } >>output.txt 2>>error.txt
cd ..
```

Comment: I guess it's better to go with `{ }` over `( )` when possible but a nice side-effect of the subshell is that there's no need to change directory afterwards.

Comment: Yes true but usually a `cd -` takes care of it and forking a subshell has many more side effects than this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a subshell `(...)` to collect all the outputs in a single stream:

```
( cd ... && ... && git pull origin master ) >> output.txt 2>>error.txt
```

This solves both problems since the streams are prepared before the `cd` command.